# How to get a city road network as line segments?

Tags: qgis, road, geometric-network

I want to have road-network information of different cities(New York for example) in the format of line segments(i.e. every road is represented by segment(s)). I want this for experimental purposes in my college project. I have looked into using QGIS however I am unable to get what I want as I am totally new to the platform. To be precise the question is as follows:

Input : A city name

Output : File containing a list of segments which together approximates the road network of the input city.

I have installed the openlayers plugin in qgis, but as I am totally new I don't know how to use it and where to start. Any pointers will be appreciated.

**UPDATE:**

So far I was able to get upto a road network in QGIS. This was done as follows(e.g. for a city in India):

1. Downloaded India Shapefile from gadm.org
2. Extracted the city I wanted into a new shapefile(Select city from attribute table, and do a vector clip)
3. Got road shapefile for India from http://download.geofabrik.de/asia/india.html and again did a Geometric intersect with the shapefile obtained in step 2. Saved this as a new shapefile.

Now there is only one hurdle remaining. I have a road network for a city in my hands as a shapefile. How do I convert the road network into co-ordinates for line segments which approximate the network(i.e. each straight segment in the shapefile is represented by two co-ordinates, I want all these co-ordinates).
Any pointers on this would be really helpful.

Answer (score 2):

It's not going to be as easy as you expect.

- Firstly you need a data source. Your best option for this is OpenStreetMaps' Database. But if you take the entire world, the data is in 100s of GBs.
- Secondly, you will need a source for your cities. You will need a polygon source, which indicates the boundary of the city, so that you can then select the streets inside it. However finding this source is going to be an hard task. I know of no source that will give the boundary of each and every city in the world. You will have to integrate and collect this data yourself, from various sources.
- Once you have these two, you will first have to get the boundary of the input city, and then select the roads that lie within it.

Comment: 1. true. 2.  see http://www.gadm.org/  is a good start.

Comment: @simplexio: Please show me where in gadm do you get city boundries? I have never found those in gadm.

Comment: IF he wants only US data, then the [BTS census transportation planning package](http://www.transtats.bts.gov/tables.asp?DB_ID=630) might be a better option than OpenStreetMap

Comment: @Devdatta Tengshe: In Finnish data FIN_adm4 (type Municipality) file, column NAME_4 is city, i have assumed that other countries data has similiar columns and values

Comment: @simplexio It is not there in most of the countries. I have checked for US, UK & India.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe thanks for this, I have got a superficial idea of what to do, But still I don't know how to do all this in QGIS, can you give me some pointers where I can read up and do all that you have mentioned? Also how do I finally get the road network into a format of line segments which approximates the entire network?

Comment: btw I was able to get upto city information, e.g. I downloaded India shapefile from the site mentioned by simplexio, then included the shapefile as a vector layer, then opening the attribute table of the shape gives a list of cities for the ind_adm2 shapefile, from this simply select the city of your choice

Comment: @anupj ind_adm2 is the shapefile containing districts, not cities.

Comment: @DevdattaTengshe yes you are right, my mistake, ind_adm3 has cities...